# python2 use tesseract C-API crash

Tags: python, tesseract

I've install tesseract4.0, and can use tesseract by command line to identy pictures. But when I try to use C-API according to [official wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample), the python program crashed with `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`, and no more other error information. It crashed at line `rc = tesseract.TessBaseAPIInit3(api, TESSDATA_PREFIX, lang)`. Here is My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import ctypes

lang = "chi_sim"
filename = "/Users/pzx/Desktop/test.png"
libname = "/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.4.dylib"
TESSDATA_PREFIX = os.environ.get('TESSDATA_PREFIX')
if not TESSDATA_PREFIX:
    TESSDATA_PREFIX = "/usr/local/share"

tesseract = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libname)
tesseract.TessVersion.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
tesseract_version = tesseract.TessVersion()
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPICreate()
rc = tesseract.TessBaseAPIInit3(api, TESSDATA_PREFIX, lang)
if (rc):
    tesseract.TessBaseAPIDelete(api)
    print("Could not initialize tesseract.\n")
    exit(3)

text_out = tesseract.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(api, filename, None, 0)
result_text = ctypes.string_at(text_out)

print 'Tesseract-ocr version', tesseract_version
print result_text
```

Here is my tesseract version info:

```
tesseract 4.00.00alpha
 leptonica-1.74.4
  libjpeg 9b : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11

 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

python version info:

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 25 2017, 09:53:22)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How can I fix it, every answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you check if `tessdata` folder exist in your `TESSDATA_PREFIX` path

Comment: Yes there is `tessdata ` in `/usr/local/share`.

Comment: @Dmitrii Z. I‘ve checked [tesseract-c_api-demo.py](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/contrib/tesseract-c_api-demo.py), it include windows & linux system, does the C-API not support MacOS? `if sys.platform == "win32":
 libname = libpath_w + "libtesseract302.dll"
 libname_alt = "libtesseract302.dll"
 os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + libpath_w
else:
 libname = libpath + "libtesseract.so.3.0.2"
 libname_alt = "libtesseract.so.3"`

Comment: I tried to build tesseract in ubuntu 16.04, then previous error line `rc = tesseract.TessBaseAPIInit3(api, TESSDATA_PREFIX, lang)` did't crash, but line `text_out = tesseract.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(api, filename, None, 0)` crashed at last.Error msg is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.